# Pass (Send) Json string to Controller using jQuery AJAX in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am having trouble passing the data to the controller. Here is my code below.

Javascript:

```js
let memberID = $("#MemberID").val();
const element = document.querySelectorAll('[index-id]');
let imax = element.length;
let SOData = `{MemberID: ${memberID}, SalesOrderDetails:[`;
let i = 0;
let salesOrders = [];

while (i < imax) {
    let ubound = 5;
    let indexid = element[i].attributes["index-id"].nodeValue;
    let prodID = element[i].attributes["selected-id"].nodeValue;
    console.log("prodID: " + prodID);
    let quantity = 0.00;
    let unitPrice = 0.00;
    let tax = 0.00;
    for (x = 1; x <= ubound; x++) {
        let value = element[i].value;
        if (x == 2) {
            quantity = value;
        }
        else if (x == 3) {
            unitPrice = value;
        }
        else if (x == 4) {
            tax += value;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    salesOrders.push(
        {
            "ProductID": parseInt(prodID),
            "Quantity": parseInt(quantity),
            "UnitPrice": parseFloat(unitPrice),
            "Tax": parseFloat(tax),
            "Discount": 0.00,
        }
    )
}

$.ajax('/SalesOrder/CreateOrder', {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { SalesOrderDetail: JSON.stringify(salesOrders) },
    traditional: true,
    success: function (d) {
        console.log(d);
    }
});
```

This is my code on the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateOrder(List<SalesOrderDetail> SalesOrderDetail)
{
   //This is the controller

    return null;
}
```

Here is my Class that I used:

```
public class SalesOrderDetail
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
}
```

Please let me code what the issue is. It seems that there is no value that has been passed to the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`salesOrders` is defined as arrry `[]`, so then you use `JSON.stringify` to convert it to a JSON object, there's no key name for this array, and that's the reason why your controller can't get the list data. You should remove `contentType` and `JSON.stringify`.

```
$("#btn2").click(function(){
    var salesOrders = [];
    var obj = {
        "ProductID": 123,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "UnitPrice": parseFloat("12.7"),
        "Tax": parseFloat("0.2"),
        "Discount": 0.00,
    };
     var obj2 = {
        "ProductID": 124,
        "Quantity": 2,
        "UnitPrice": parseFloat("19.6"),
        "Tax": parseFloat("0.2"),
        "Discount": 0.00,
    };
    salesOrders.push(obj);
    salesOrders.push(obj2);
    console.log(salesOrders);
    $.ajax({
        url:"https://localhost:44316/home/CreateOrder",
        type:'post',
        data:{
            SalesOrderDetail: salesOrders
        },
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
     });
});

[HttpPost]
public string CreateOrder(List<SalesOrderDetail> SalesOrderDetail)
{
    return "success";
}
```

[image]

And Per my test, if you have to use `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`, you can try code below, it also worked:

```
[HttpPost]
public string CreateOrder([FromBody]List<SalesOrderDetail> salesOrders)
{
    return "success";
}

$.ajax({
    url:"https://localhost:44316/home/CreateOrder",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type:'post',
    data:JSON.stringify(salesOrders),
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
 });
```