# ASP.Net MVC Sending Table data from view to controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a table in my view for what is essentially my attempt at making a timesheet table. It also contains a button for adding more rows to the table.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover" id="mytab" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  
        <thead>
            <tr>  
                <th>Project</th>   
                <th>Discipline</th>  
                <th>Mo</th>  
                <th>Tu</th>  
                <th>We</th>  
                <th>Thu</th>  
                <th>Fri</th>  
                <th>Sat</th>  
                <th>Sun</th>  
                <th></th>
            </tr>  
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td><select name="selectedProjectId" asp-items="@ViewData["projectSubProject"] as SelectList" class="form-control-plaintext align-content-around">
            </select></td>  
            <td><select name="selectedPositionId" asp-items="@ViewData["Positions"] as SelectList" class="form-control-plaintext align-content-around"></select></td>  
            <td><input class="form-control-plaintext align-content-around txtCal" type="number" min="1" max="24"/></td>  
            <td><input class="form-control-plaintext align-content-around txtCal" type="number" min="1" max="24"/></td>  
            <td><input class="form-control-plaintext align-content-around txtCal" type="number" min="1" max="24"/></td>  
            <td><input class="form-control-plaintext align-content-around txtCal" type="number" min="1" max="24"/></td>  
            <td><input class="form-control-plaintext align-content-around txtCal" type="number" min="1" max="24"/></td>  
            <td><input class="form-control-plaintext align-content-around txtCal" type="number" min="1" max="24"/></td>  
            <td><input class="form-control-plaintext align-content-around txtCal" type="number" min="1" max="24"/></td> 
        </tr>
    </table> 
    <br />
    <form action="">
        <input type="button" value="Add a Row" onclick="addRow()">
    </form>
```

[It looks like this in the web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMhzI.png)

The script for adding rows to the table and the script for what **should**, from what i gather, send the table data in json format to controller on table data change look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myTable").on('input', '.txtCal', function () {
               var calculated_total_sum = 0;
 
               $("#myTable .txtCal").each(function () {
                   var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
                   if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
                      calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
                      }                  
                    });
                      $("#total_sum_value").html(calculated_total_sum);
               });

        });

        function addRow() {
            var root = document.getElementById('mytab').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
            var rows = root.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            var clone = cloneEl(rows[rows.length - 1]);
            cleanUpInputs(clone);
            root.appendChild(clone);
        }
        
        function cloneEl(el) {
            var clo = el.cloneNode(true);
            return clo;
        }

        function cleanUpInputs(obj) {
          for (var i = 0; n = obj.childNodes[i]; ++i) {
            if (n.childNodes && n.tagName != 'INPUT') {
              cleanUpInputs(n);
            } else if (n.tagName == 'INPUT' && n.type == 'number') {
              n.value = '';
            }
          }  
        }

        $('input').change(function () {
            var table = document.getElementById("mytab");
            var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            var data = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var cells = rows[i].getElementsByClassName("form-control-plaintext");
                var row = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                    var cell = cells[j];
                    row.push(cell.innerText);
                }
                data.push(row);
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("TableList", "Home")',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert("can not update the timesheet");
                }
            });
        });
```

And finally, my controller methods look like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TableList()
    {
        var projectSubProject = await _context.SubProject.Include(x => x.Project).ToListAsync();
        ViewData["projectSubProject"] = new SelectList(projectSubProject, "Id", "DisplayId");
        ViewData["Positions"] = new SelectList(await _context.Position.ToListAsync(), "Id", "Title");

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TableList([FromBody] List<object> data)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

The problem that i think i'm encountering is that the JSON data doesn't actually reach the controller, since putting a break point anywhere on the Post method doesn't ever trigger it.

Am i doing something wrong? Am i missing some crucial step? Is there perhaps an easier way of doing what i want to do?

**UPDATE**

I've now managed to send my data to the controller. However, the data that does reach the controller isn't correct.
[image: The data looks like this]

As you can see, it gets all of the options of the select, instead of only my selected option. It also doesn't get any of the numbers through.

I've updated all of my code to reflect the current situation.

Comment: have you checked the request payload when you send the ajax request?

Comment: how is it going on? any update on it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I still can't get it to work. I've tried changing they way i submit all the information to something like a form submit, but even then, to no avail. I Got the data to actually reach the controller a few times, however, the data that does reach it, isn't formed corretly

Comment: have you tried my code snippet? if it didn't work for you, could you pls update your question to show us your latest code?

Comment: I've updated it now

Comment: actually it's another question... Your original question is that you failed to send table data to controller, but now it becomes that the data send to controller doesn't meet your requirement. Let's see your js code, you looped all the <tr> attribute to get each value of <input> the push all of them in to array. There's no `selected option` existed in your code. Hence, if you had trouble to gather target data and pass them to the controller, I recommend you creating a new question about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a Model for that something like a Row class list.

Like this:

```
public class Row
{
    public string Project   {get;set;}
    public string Discipline {get;set;} 
    public string Mo  {get;set;}
    public string Tu  {get;set;}
    public string We  {get;set;}
    public string Thu  {get;set;}
    public string Fri  {get;set;}
    public string Sat  {get;set;}
    public string Sun  {get;set;}
}

public class TableModel
{
    public List<Row> Rows {get; set;}
}
```

And then I would set all the actions to interact with the model.

This would make your work easier.

I also suggest to take a look at [the microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/overview/understanding-models-views-and-controllers-cs) since you are missing the use of models.

Answer (score 0):

There're several points you need to care. Firstly, you are now trying to use ajax to send post request to your controller, it's different from the default form submit in asp.net core MVC. Hence, `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` and `if (ModelState.IsValid)` are not suitable for your scenario.

Then, when you use `data: JSON.stringify(data)` to set it as the request data, it will generate payload like this, you can't use `string` to receive the data, you need to use `List<object> data`:

[image]
[image]
[image]

You may change your code like this:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            var data = [];
            var row1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
            var row2 = [6,7,8,9,10];
            data.push(row1);
            data.push(row2);
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://localhost:7175/Home/TableList",
                type: "post",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}

[HttpPost]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public string TableList([FromBody]List<object> data)
{
    //if (ModelState.IsValid) { 
    //    var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    //}
    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: I have another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71463341/15581227) which is a little similar with your scenario, you may take a look at it.